# Searching and Matching word with mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to match words of my search query to my table in sql database but I am failed to do so please tell me what should I do. Thanks

```
mysql table 'mytable'
ID | words
0  | cars 
1  | blue car
2  | red 
3  | green car
4  | tank
5  | car
```

Mysql query

```
$query = "Select * from `mytable`";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
$w = $row['words'];
$i =  " ".$w." " ; 
}
```

Search Word

```
$search = 'red car';
```

Matching with database

```
$mywords = split(" ",$i); 
$split_strings = preg_split('/[\ \n\,]+/', $search);
$result = array_intersect($split_strings, $mywords);
if(!empty($result))
{ 
echo 'Matched';
}
else {
echo 'Not Matched';
}
```

I want it to be result in 'Matched' but it is echoing 'Not Matched'

Comment: select * from 'words' ? are you sure? your table name is mytable

Comment: Why don't you use `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE words LIKE '%$search%'` ?

Comment: @Raptor It doesn't fullfill my requirements as it searches different like if in database a word is 'card' and I searched for 'car' it will match with it.

Comment: then using `where words = '$search'`

Comment: @John it didnot match with other words if you used  query like this SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE words LIKE '$search'

Comment: What if in table word is 'blue car' and If I search like 'where words = 'car'' it will not match either.

Comment: just remove the '%' at the end of $search
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE words LIKE '%$search'

Comment: This is temporary solution bro. It will match 'black' if I search for 'lack'

Comment: @John wait. i m doing this

Answer (score 0):

I have run this code, the only issue i have faced is the split function as it is deprecated. so i changed

```
$mywords = split(" ",$i);
```

to

```
$mywords = preg_split('/[\ \n\,]+/',$i);
```

fixed your array problem

```
  $data=array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
    $w = $row['words'];
    $i =  " ".$w." " ;
    $data[]=$i; 
    }
 for($i=0;$i<sizeof($data);$i++)
{   
$mywords=preg_split('/[\ \n\,]+/', $data[$i]);
$result = array_intersect($mywords,$search);
   if($result)
   {
      echo "Matched";
      break;
   }
}
if(!$result)
   {
     echo "No matched";
   }
```

Comment: So how can I get matched it with all queries not just single.

Comment: you can save the value of $row['words'] into an array

Comment: I solved the issue with mysql as preg_split or split is not working because of mysql getting only last query.

Comment: @John updated the answer it now worked for every row

Comment: getting error 
`Warning: array_intersect(): Argument #2 is not an array in`

Comment: also it is looping 'Not Matched'.

Comment: yes i have changed that part.. lokk at the edited answer

Comment: Yeah it stopped looping but still can't match the word. Just leave it as I have solved it with mysql with the old method of where word like '$search';